# Proving P(x) > 0 given a condition.

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

$P(x)$ is a polynomial function such that,

$P(1) = 0, P′(x) > P(x), ∀ x > 1. $

Prove that 
$P(x) > 0, ∀ x > 1.$

I was trying to do by taking the P(x) in the denominator and then integrating from 0 to 1 but log(0) is not defined so I couldn't proceed.

Comment: For future questions here is http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for properly displaying functions.

Comment: I may be confused, but... can such a polynomial exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not seem to be true. First, note that $P$ is not the zero polynomial, otherwise $P^\prime(x) > P(x)$ cannot hold.

Write $P(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k x^k$, where $n$ is the degree of $P$ ($a_n \neq 0$). Then $P^\prime$ has degree $n-1$, and for $x\to\infty$ we have $P(x) \sim_{x\to\infty} a_n x^n$ and $P^\prime(x) \sim_{x\to\infty} n a_n x^{n-1}$ (so that $\frac{P^\prime}{P} \to 0$). Therefore, $P^\prime(x) > P(x)$ can only asymptotically hold if $a_n < 0$. (Since if $a_n > 0$, then $P(x) > P^\prime(x)$ for $x$ large enough).

But then, we have $P(x) \xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{} -\infty$, so "$P(x) > 0 \forall x > 1$" certainly does not hold.

Comment: It's from a competitive exam in India called the IIT JEE from the year 2003.